# JavaScript use complex json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to show a json data into a html table.But json file is very complex. I tried but not find a correct solution for it. Please correct my code so that it will work.I am here adding all my files please solve my query.

index.php

```
<html>
<header><title>Welcome</title></header>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src=index.js></script>



<h1>VIDEO LIST</h1>
   <table class="button" id= "userdata" width="100%" border="20">
            <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME</th>
            <th>LINK</th>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</tr>

</html>
```

index.js

```
$("#userdata tbody").empty();



var b = location.search.split('b=')[1];

$.get(
    "index2.php",
    {"b":b},
    function(data) {
alert(data);
var datas = JSON.parse(data);
 $.each(datas.liveVideoList , function(i, v) {

    var str = v.thumbnailUrl.split("vi/").pop();

    var datee = v.publishDate.slice(0,9);
    var timee = v.publishDate.slice(9,20);

     var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + v.title + "</td>"+ "<td>" +  0 + '  ₹' + "</td>" + "<td>" + datee + "</td>" +"<td>"+ timee + "</td>"  + "<td><a target='_blank' href='"+str+"'>"+"WATCH/DOWNLOAD"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>";


          $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata");





     });
    }
);
```

Json file

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":23,"course":{"categoriesId":[1],"shortName":"Computer Special","courseUrl":"/courses/23","statusCode":1,"statusName":"Active","productType":1,"isWithSections":true,"sectionsId":[67],"classTiming":"Classes End. Course Removed On :05th December 2019","enrollStartedAt":"7/25/2019 12:00:00 AM","enrollEndAt":"11/15/2019 12:00:00 AM","courseStartedAt":"8/1/2019 12:00:00 AM","courseEndAt":"12/5/2019 12:00:00 AM","courseExpiredAt":"12/5/2019 12:00:00 AM","isEnrollStarted":false,"isEnrollEnd":true,"isCourseStarted":false,"isCourseEnd":true,"isCourseExpired":true,"coursePrice":39900.0,"discountPrice":0.0,"discountComment":"\"USE PROMOCODE NEW50\"","courseDetails":{},"courseFeatures":{},"courseValidity":120,"teachersId":[18],"about":"","requirements":"","studentEnrolled":0,"faqsId":[],"examsId":[],"displayOrder":0,"tags":[],"isLive":false,"admissionStatus":false,"metas":[],"teacherList":[{"name":"Manvendra Sir","thumbnailUrl":"https://timescoaching.in/content/img/teachers/manvendera.png","experience":"Computer","about":"","statusCode":1,"statusName":"Active","id":18,"createdAt":"7/31/2019 4:00:00 PM","modifiedAt":"7/31/2019 4:00:00 PM","createdBy":1,"modifiedBy":1}],"examList":[],"faqList":[],"categoryList":[],"subscriptionList":[],"introVideoUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/meliFYc1VRw","subscriptionStartAt":"","subscriptionEndAt":"","name":"Computer Special","heading":"","thumbnailUrl":"https://timescoaching.in/content/img/computer.png","metaTitle":"Computer (03:30 PM To 05:00 PM) ","metaKeywords":"","metaDescription":"","content":"","settings":{"taxPercent":18.0,"productTax":0,"taxAppliedType":2,"authType":1,"isDiscountApplied":true,"maxDiscountPercent":0.0},"id":23,"createdAt":"7/23/2019 10:40:00 AM","modifiedAt":"7/23/2019 10:40:00 AM","createdBy":1,"modifiedBy":1},"schedules":[{"id":67,"title":"Computer","thumbnailUrl":"https://timescoaching.in/content/img/teachers/manvendera.png","heading":"Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"7/31/2019 12:00:00 AM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"liveVideoList":[{"id":2420,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 31 [04:00 PM - 05:30 PM 11 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/g4l12zBsRGU/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/11/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1407,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2397,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 30 [04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 10 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/EPLwnlnNzoI/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/10/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1390,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2378,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 29 [04:00 PM - 05:30 PM 09 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/ij_SRFFIpLk/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/9/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1378,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2326,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 28 [04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 03 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/phgnyn9ikhc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"10/3/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1338,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2283,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 27 [04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 01 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/STTCghpnR4M/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/1/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1314,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2252,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 26 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 30 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/EsXusfsnQrI/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/30/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1295,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2224,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 25 [05:00 PM - 06:00 PM 28 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/-W_GFxFYmhc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/28/2019 5:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1276,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2073,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 24 [04:00 \r\nPM - 05:30 PM 18 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/p112TfWFhbg/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/18/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1175,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2016,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 21 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 14 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/hqXJDh-E5os/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/14/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1139,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2005,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 20 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 13 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/hqPxYaprKqU/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/13/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1131,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1985,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 19 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 12 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/1CtZG7cieU0/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/12/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1115,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1926,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 18 [03:30 PM - 06:00 PM 09 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/oj06bE83KIc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/9/2019 3:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1085,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1881,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 17 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 06 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/ZYAvkDq-8bY/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/6/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1060,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1867,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 16 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 04 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/p36QauR69GY/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/4/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1049,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1855,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 15 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 03 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/emqJh4zcC2s/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/3/2019 3:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1040,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1841,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 14 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 02 september 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/VhGKe3qyW_o/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/2/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1031,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1779,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -13 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 29 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/xuDx4Pb0a54/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"8/29/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":996,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1769,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 12 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 28 August 2019","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/a55W9kwu7Ko/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/28/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":989,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1755,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 11[03:30 PM 05:00 PM 27 August 2019","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/sPf4ZXDPiwQ/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/27/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":980,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1728,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 10[04:00 PM 05:00 PM 26 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/SAQBpUw9OPU/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/26/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":968,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1637,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 9[05:00 PM 06:30 PM 21 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Zb2mi77lU4g/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by manavendra sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/21/2019 4:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":918,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1601,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 8[03:00 PM 04:30 PM 20 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/eQdojpCPw7k/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir\r\n","description":"","publishDate":"8/20/2019 2:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":904,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1536,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 7 [17 August 2019 03:30 PM 05:00 PM]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/0721FF5n_3o/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir\r\n","description":"","publishDate":"8/17/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":885,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1489,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 6 [13 August 2019 03:30 PM 05:00 PM]\n","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bc9lSJTObyc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/13/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":872,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1459,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 5 [03:30 PM 5:00 PM 12 August]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/GgOWFs9QWlM/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/12/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":857,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1439,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 4 [03:30 PM 5:00 PM 10 August]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/INTNupllJ3E/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/10/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":844,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1384,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -3[05:00 PM 6:30 PM 07 August]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/vOO2TbUUa0Q/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir\r\n","description":"","publishDate":"8/7/2019 4:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":805,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1370,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -2[05:00 PM 6:30 PM 06 August]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/dJejWFQjUM8/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/6/2019 4:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":794,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1289,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -1 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 01 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/2NqWuzBadhg/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/1/2019 3:20:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":749,"isAvaiable":true,"availability":0,"isFree":true}],"assignmentList":[{"id":2624,"sectionId":67,"title":"Q & A Computer","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/22/2019 1:00:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1374,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2625,"sectionId":67,"title":"Computer","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/22/2019 1:00:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1375,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2499,"sectionId":67,"title":"1500 Questions On Computer Awareness","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/15/2019 1:00:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1358,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1738,"sectionId":67,"title":"Database","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment by Manvendera Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/26/2019 12:04:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1218,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1739,"sectionId":67,"title":"Computer Awareness Bank PO","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment by Manvendera Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/26/2019 12:04:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1219,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false}]}]},"status":1,"message":"Details Fetched","androidAppVersion":"3.0.2"}{"success":true,"data":{"id":23,"course":{"categoriesId":[1],"shortName":"Computer Special","courseUrl":"/courses/23","statusCode":1,"statusName":"Active","productType":1,"isWithSections":true,"sectionsId":[67],"classTiming":"Classes End. Course Removed On :05th December 2019","enrollStartedAt":"7/25/2019 12:00:00 AM","enrollEndAt":"11/15/2019 12:00:00 AM","courseStartedAt":"8/1/2019 12:00:00 AM","courseEndAt":"12/5/2019 12:00:00 AM","courseExpiredAt":"12/5/2019 12:00:00 AM","isEnrollStarted":false,"isEnrollEnd":true,"isCourseStarted":false,"isCourseEnd":true,"isCourseExpired":true,"coursePrice":39900.0,"discountPrice":0.0,"discountComment":"\"USE PROMOCODE NEW50\"","courseDetails":{},"courseFeatures":{},"courseValidity":120,"teachersId":[18],"about":"","requirements":"","studentEnrolled":0,"faqsId":[],"examsId":[],"displayOrder":0,"tags":[],"isLive":false,"admissionStatus":false,"metas":[],"teacherList":[{"name":"Manvendra Sir","thumbnailUrl":"https://timescoaching.in/content/img/teachers/manvendera.png","experience":"Computer","about":"","statusCode":1,"statusName":"Active","id":18,"createdAt":"7/31/2019 4:00:00 PM","modifiedAt":"7/31/2019 4:00:00 PM","createdBy":1,"modifiedBy":1}],"examList":[],"faqList":[],"categoryList":[],"subscriptionList":[],"introVideoUrl":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/meliFYc1VRw","subscriptionStartAt":"","subscriptionEndAt":"","name":"Computer Special","heading":"","thumbnailUrl":"https://timescoaching.in/content/img/computer.png","metaTitle":"Computer (03:30 PM To 05:00 PM) ","metaKeywords":"","metaDescription":"","content":"","settings":{"taxPercent":18.0,"productTax":0,"taxAppliedType":2,"authType":1,"isDiscountApplied":true,"maxDiscountPercent":0.0},"id":23,"createdAt":"7/23/2019 10:40:00 AM","modifiedAt":"7/23/2019 10:40:00 AM","createdBy":1,"modifiedBy":1},"schedules":[{"id":67,"title":"Computer","thumbnailUrl":"https://timescoaching.in/content/img/teachers/manvendera.png","heading":"Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"7/31/2019 12:00:00 AM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"liveVideoList":[{"id":2420,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 31 [04:00 PM - 05:30 PM 11 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/g4l12zBsRGU/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/11/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1407,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2397,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 30 [04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 10 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/EPLwnlnNzoI/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/10/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1390,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2378,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 29 [04:00 PM - 05:30 PM 09 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/ij_SRFFIpLk/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/9/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1378,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2326,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 28 [04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 03 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/phgnyn9ikhc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"10/3/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1338,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2283,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 27 [04:00 PM - 05:00 PM 01 October 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/STTCghpnR4M/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/1/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1314,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2252,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 26 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 30 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/EsXusfsnQrI/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/30/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1295,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2224,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 25 [05:00 PM - 06:00 PM 28 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/-W_GFxFYmhc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/28/2019 5:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1276,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2073,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 24 [04:00 \r\nPM - 05:30 PM 18 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/p112TfWFhbg/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/18/2019 4:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1175,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2016,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 21 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 14 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/hqXJDh-E5os/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/14/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1139,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2005,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 20 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 13 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/hqPxYaprKqU/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/13/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1131,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1985,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 19 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 12 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/1CtZG7cieU0/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/12/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1115,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1926,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 18 [03:30 PM - 06:00 PM 09 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/oj06bE83KIc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/9/2019 3:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1085,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1881,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 17 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 06 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/ZYAvkDq-8bY/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/6/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1060,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1867,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 16 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 04 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/p36QauR69GY/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/4/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1049,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1855,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 15 [03:30 PM - 05:00 PM 03 September 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/emqJh4zcC2s/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"9/3/2019 3:00:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1040,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1841,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 14 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 02 september 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/VhGKe3qyW_o/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"9/2/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":1031,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1779,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -13 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 29 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/xuDx4Pb0a54/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manvendra Sir ","description":"","publishDate":"8/29/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":996,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1769,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 12 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 28 August 2019","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/a55W9kwu7Ko/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/28/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":989,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1755,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 11[03:30 PM 05:00 PM 27 August 2019","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/sPf4ZXDPiwQ/default.jpg","heading":"Computer By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/27/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":980,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1728,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 10[04:00 PM 05:00 PM 26 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/SAQBpUw9OPU/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/26/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":968,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1637,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 9[05:00 PM 06:30 PM 21 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Zb2mi77lU4g/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by manavendra sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/21/2019 4:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":918,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1601,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 8[03:00 PM 04:30 PM 20 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/eQdojpCPw7k/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir\r\n","description":"","publishDate":"8/20/2019 2:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":904,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1536,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 7 [17 August 2019 03:30 PM 05:00 PM]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/0721FF5n_3o/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir\r\n","description":"","publishDate":"8/17/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":885,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1489,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 6 [13 August 2019 03:30 PM 05:00 PM]\n","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/bc9lSJTObyc/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/13/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":872,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1459,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 5 [03:30 PM 5:00 PM 12 August]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/GgOWFs9QWlM/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/12/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":857,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1439,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture - 4 [03:30 PM 5:00 PM 10 August]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/INTNupllJ3E/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/10/2019 3:25:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":844,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1384,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -3[05:00 PM 6:30 PM 07 August]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/vOO2TbUUa0Q/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir\r\n","description":"","publishDate":"8/7/2019 4:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":805,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1370,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -2[05:00 PM 6:30 PM 06 August]","thumbnailUrl":"http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/dJejWFQjUM8/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/6/2019 4:55:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":794,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1289,"sectionId":67,"title":"Live Class Lecture -1 [03:30 PM 05:00 PM 01 August 2019]","thumbnailUrl":"https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/2NqWuzBadhg/default.jpg","heading":"Computer by Manvendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/1/2019 3:20:00 PM","isLive":false,"displayOrder":0,"videoId":749,"isAvaiable":true,"availability":0,"isFree":true}],"assignmentList":[{"id":2624,"sectionId":67,"title":"Q & A Computer","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/22/2019 1:00:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1374,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2625,"sectionId":67,"title":"Computer","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment By Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/22/2019 1:00:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1375,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":2499,"sectionId":67,"title":"1500 Questions On Computer Awareness","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Manavendra Sir","description":"","publishDate":"10/15/2019 1:00:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1358,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1738,"sectionId":67,"title":"Database","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment by Manvendera Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/26/2019 12:04:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1218,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false},{"id":1739,"sectionId":67,"title":"Computer Awareness Bank PO","thumbnailUrl":"","heading":"Assignment by Manvendera Sir","description":"","publishDate":"8/26/2019 12:04:00 PM","displayOrder":0,"downloadId":1219,"isAvaiable":false,"availability":0,"isFree":false}]}]},"status":1,"message":"Details Fetched","androidAppVersion":"3.0.2"}
```

Comment: What error you facing?

Comment: The JSON seems to be incorrectly formatted. You squished two together into one.

Comment: Thanks Sir it works.But i have to use ```json.data.schedules[0].liveVideoList ``` , ```json.data.schedules[1 ].liveVideoList```  and so on Please tell me how can i use loop here

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data provided seems to be pasted twice, so I attempted to correct the JSON and modify the code so everything works correctly.

You might want to look more into HTML, as there were numerous things that went wrong.

- You want to use `<head>` not `<header>`
- You want to put the script tag(s) after the elements in your `<body>` to allow the script to interact with the elements. If not, this can cause more annoying errors.
- Tables should be correctly formatted with a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`
- Preferrably, links to stylesheets should be put in the `<head>`

The JS was mostly working, you just needed to correctly reference the `liveVideoList`. You need to reference the path to the `liveVideoList` instead of just putting the name. In this case, it would look like `json.data.schedules[0].liveVideoList`.

**Modified HTML:**

```
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>VIDEO LIST</h1>
    <table class="button" id="userdata" width="100%" border="20">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
                <th>LINK</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Modified JavaScript:**

```
$("#userdata tbody").empty();

var b = location.search.split('b=')[1];

$.get(
    "index2.php",
    { "b": b },
    function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);

        $.each(json.data.schedules, function (j, w) {
            $.each(w.liveVideoList, function (i, v) {
                var str = v.thumbnailUrl.split("vi/").pop();

                var datee = v.publishDate.slice(0, 9);
                var timee = v.publishDate.slice(9, 20);

                var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + v.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + 0 + '  ₹' + "</td>" + "<td>" + datee + "</td>" + "<td>" + timee + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='" + str + "'>" + "WATCH/DOWNLOAD" + "</a></td>" + "</tr>";

                $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata");
            });
        });
    }
);
```

Modified Working Code: https://repl.it/@DrewSnow/JavaScript-use-complex-json-file

Comment: Thanks Sir it works.But i have to use ```json.data.schedules[0].liveVideoList ``` , ```json.data.schedules[1 ].liveVideoList```  and so on Please tell me how can i use loop here

Comment: Again Thanks for help and also your code is working